# Clearing rather than releasing a NSMutableString

Tags: iphone, nsmutablestring

I've got a rather large loop that gets a string, does something to it, than goes onto the next one. I was originally releasing it then reallocating it but thought that is a bit of waste of resources but can't figure out how to just clear it out to reuse it.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

One way would be `[myString setString: @""]`.

Comment: Thats annoying, I actually tried that and it crashed so thought it wouldn't work. Ended up I left another statement which crashed it.

Answer (score 1):

The selected solution will crash with the following error:

'Attempt to mutate immutable object with setString:'

This worked for me instead:

self.myString = [NSMutableString stringWithString:@""];

make sure you synthesize myString in your class.

Comment: Agreed. Setting an NSMutableString to an NSString is not good. The error you get in Xcode 4.4 is "Incompatible pointer types sending 'NSString *' to parameter of type 'NSMutableString *'". Setting it with this solution is better.

Comment: It seems to me that this is allocating a new NSMutableString instance? Is that not just as much a waste of resources as in the original question?

Comment: If you get 'Attempt to mutate immutable object with setString:' then the string you're trying to modify is not an `NSMutableString`, and you're dealing with a different problem than "Clearing rather than releasing a NSMutableString", the title of this question.